# Access 2013 Error: #Name?

Tags: ms-access

I have created a textbox that has the control source set to a field in the database. The table is called tbPriceRange and the fields are called PriceRangeOne and PriceRangeTwo

In the control source i said `=[tbPriceRange]![PriceRangeOne]` 
My textbox is called PriceOne

So where is the naming error? I can't get it can someone help me out?

Edit: 
For the form i use tbTagesAngebote as table
for the Textboxes I want to use tbPriceRange which is a different table

Answer (score 0):

The `Control source` is a name of a field in the Form's `Record Source` Property.
Enter in Forms `Record Source` Property: `tbPriceRange`, and in TextBox `Control source` Property: `PriceRangeOne`.

If Form has other `Record Source`, you can use an expression, or function (like `DLookup()`) as textbox `Control source` Property. Like:  `=DLookup("PriceRangeOne","tbPriceRange",Criteria)`.
In this case, TextBox becomes *read only*.

Comment: As I wrote: Enter in Form's Record Source Property: tbPriceRange, and in TextBox Control source Property: PriceRangeOne.

Comment: For the form I'm using this `SELECT tbTagesAngebote.* FROM tbTagesAngebote` ... I can't change this to tbPriceRange

Comment: See if you can join tbPriceRange to tbTagesAngebote

Comment: I tried this already but access wont let me do this because it's `tbTagesAngebote.*` when i select everything seperatly I tried to `Union` but `tbPriceRange` has not the same amount of columns

Comment: The value of witch record do you want to see in `tbPriceRange`? is there some Common field with `tbTagesAngebote`? Show your table structure, and some data

Comment: I created `PriceRangeOne` and `PriceRangeTwo` in tbTagesAngebote but this won't work as i wan't it to work because if a user enters a PriceRange than it would save it to a Record and the Range would only display to this Record ... I need the Range global for when he enters a range it should be there until he changes it to another Pricerange

Comment: **EDIT:** I understand tbPriceRange has one record, and two fields? How about `SELECT * FROM tbTagesAngebote Inner Join tbPriceRange`?

Comment: when i do this it destroys my whole form ... I shouldn't do it that way .. do you maybe a way to store it in global variables and display it again with the variable?

Comment: a global variable won't update the DB. What do you mean '*destroys*'?

Comment: It's not displaying forms or reports anylonger for example that's what i mean with destroys ... and i won't need in the database ... it should just be displayed after the user has enterd it, left the form and opened it again.