# Access 2013 - Save Value from Textbox and display again when form is opened after close

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to save a value from textbox in a string for example and display it again when the form get's openend.

I have two textboxes PriceRangeOne and PriceRangeTwo .. The user enter here for example 20 and 40

The problem i have is that when the user switches between Form and Report the values in this textboxes are beeing deleted. How can i save them?

I tried adding a sourcecontrol to the fields but had name errors eventhough i used different names.

I tried adding this to on change and retrieve it in an onload

```
Dim eingabe As String = textBox1.Text or .Value
```

Still didn't worked. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Same question as here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672645/access-2013-error-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672645/access-2013-error-name)

Comment: @marlan - This seems to be a separate (albeit somewhat related) question.  No need for a vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the most efficient and reliable way to do this is to have some form auto-open when the database is opened.  It could be a dashboard, or just some form with nothing else on it.  Whatever you use, launch it when the database opens and then minimize it.  Now you have a form that's always open, as long as the application is open.  Add a couple of textboxes to this form/dashboard.

When you close your form referenced in this question, write the values of PriceRangeOne and PriceRangeTwo to the textboxes on the form I described above.  Then, when you open a new form or report, you can reference the values in those textboxes.  Since the form is always open, you can reference these values at any time from any form or report until you close your database.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with variables.

I declared global variables in my standart module

For example

```
Public PriceOne As Double
Public PriceTwo As Double
```

Than i did this in my form in Close() and Open():

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
PriceOne = Me.Field
PriceTwo = Me.FieldTwo
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.Field = PriceOne
Me.FieldTwo = PriceTwo
End Sub
```

Works perfect!

Comment: But the variables won't persist between Access runs, will they?

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [How to save the last value of a textbox. | Access World Forums](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/how-to-save-the-last-value-of-a-textbox.282851/#post-1463360):

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
'Set the default value for textbox
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE table SET table.field = [Forms]![FormName]![Textbox] " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((table.ID)=1));"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
'Load the default value for textbox
Me.Textbox.Value = DLookup("[field]", "[table]", "[ID]=1")
End Sub
```